# redirect to data url within onBeforeRequest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, redirect, data-uri

I'm trying to redirect the request to a data url in a chrome extension using `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener`.

this is my func i send to `addListener` :

```
function (details) {        
    return {
        redirectUrl: 'data:application/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(textData)
    }
}
```

where `textData` is some Json retrieved from the server as a `String` (was not parsed yet)

and of course I'm adding the `blocking` attribute.

though it doesn't work, although it is executed on the right request, and moreover in the network panel i see "Failed to load response data" on that redirected request.

In `onBeforeRequest` documentation it says that data-URI is supported,

any one has any experience with this ?

**fixed url : ** : http://pastebin.com/zP4kjF8V

And the full addListener : (my plan is to change responseText..)

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function (details) {
        var dataAjax = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: details.url,
            async: false
        });

        return {
            redirectUrl: 'data:application/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(dataAjax.responseText)
        }
    }, {
        urls: ["someMatch-this-is-ok"]
    }, ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: How do you retrieve the `textData`? Are you certain it's defined by this point?

Comment: In general, can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: yes, textData is defined, moreover i tried to take the final data-url i got and enter in the browser and it was ok . Xan, what are u missing ?

Comment: this is a general problem, did u successfully redirected to data url this way ?

Comment: Can you make a complete example (the whole `addListener`, maybe with a fixed URL) so it's easier to test (and see if there's any other problem)

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome 47: http://pastebin.com/HkVh77ck

Comment: ive added the full function and a fixed url